# Covariance in C# generic class

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.5, covariance

C# 4.0 .NET 4.5 Silverlight 5
It seems weird that I cant find the solution so need some help please.

I have base class Base and derived class Child : Base. I have also helper class which has generic type to do specific work one EF entities Helper where T : EntityObject.

Child does specific work with a specific entity MyEntity : EntityObject.

So I tried:

```
public class Base
{
    protected Helper<EntityObject> helper;
}
public class Child : Base
{
    public Child()
    {
        helper = new Helper<MyEntity>();
    }
}
```

I would expect that more derived class must know about more specific generic parameter and I think that's what covariance for... But that doesn't work...

What's the 'correct' way to design class like that?

**EDIT:** sorry I didn't make it 100% clear why cant I achieve what I need.

**a. Solution with generic Base** doesn't work because user of the Base doesn't know the T type. Imagine:

```
public class User
{
    private Base<T> base; // this will not compile.
    public User(TypeEnum t)
    {
        if(t == TypeEnum.MyEntity) base = new Child();
...
```

**b. Solution with Interface** doesn't work because helper uses T everywhere (it is its purpose right?). Imagine it has method

```
public IEnumerable<T> Process(IEnumerable<T> items) { return items; }
```

How do I bring it up in the interface which doesn't know anything about T

Comment: What error are you seeing? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: What does `Helper` look like? What is the relationship between `MyEntity` and `EntityObject`?

Comment: Helper class is the most important piece here

Comment: @MatthewWatson MyEntity : EntityObject (see the question)

Comment: @PeterK it doesn't compile

Comment: And the error is..... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Foo` : `Bar`, that doesn't mean that `Some<Foo>` : `Some<Bar>`. There are two ways of doing what you want. The first is to make the base-type generic such that:

```
Base<T> where T : EntityObject {
    protected Helper<T> helper;
}
Child : Base<MyEntity> {...}
```

The second is to use a non-generic interface at the base-type, i.e. have

```
Base {
    protected IHelper helper;
}
Child : Base {...}
```

where in the latter case, `Helper<T> : IHelper`, for some non-generic `IHelper` to-be-defined.

As a side-note, you *might* find it easier to pass the value down in the constructor rather than using a `protected` field.

Comment: Marc. Neither of these solutions usable. Because if Base<T> then user of a Child does not know T (otherwise why do I need generics). In case of interface - you cannot declare methods in IHelper which uses T and the helper use them everythere (it is its purpose).... I updated my question with explantaions.. but I am sure you could see it yourself... is there a way out of it?

Comment: @BoppityBop indeed those are the limitations; generics aren't a magic wand that make code do something different to what it could do ordinarily

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you're after:

```
public class Base<T> where T : EntityObject
{
    protected Helper<T> helper;
}
public class Child : Base<MyEntity>
{
    public Child()
    {
        helper = new Helper<MyEntity>();
    }
}
```

Edit (in response to your edit): You can add a `Base`, use like so:

```
public class Base
{
    // put anything here that doesn't rely on the type of T
    // if you need things here that would rely on T, use EntityObject and have 
    // your subclasses provide new implementations using the more specific type
}
public class Base<T> : Base where T : EntityObject
{
    protected Helper<T> helper;
}
public class Child : Base<MyEntity>
{
    public Child()
    {
        helper = new Helper<MyEntity>();
    }
}
public class User
{
    private Base myBase;
    public User(TypeEnum t)
    {
        if(t == TypeEnum.MyEntity) myBase = new Child();
        ...
```

Comment: @BoppityBop Updated my answer; does this fit what you need? If not, I'm having trouble understanding how you'd like to use it. Maybe it'd make more sense if you could explain that: what sort of polymorphism might you need, what public members do you need on `Base`, etc.

Comment: Tim that **would** be a solution indeed... however with small problem - this won't compile either... generic argument must be present... bummer isn't it.. I would think this is a natural use for generics.. but apparently (according to SO gurus) this is magic... well... I have nothing to say.

Comment: @BoppityBop *D'oh!* I forgot to make `Base<T> : Base`. It should compile now.

Comment: sorry Tim. the solution you arrived at is a variation of the Interface problem in my Edit. User will not have access to the **benefits** of generic type T because it is shielded by Base... How am I going to use it? there is no way... it seems this has no solution.

Comment: So you're trying to let the compiler know `T` while choosing `T` via an enum value at runtime? Yes, that's impossible. Even if you make `User` into `User<T> where T : EntityObject`, the compiler only knows `T` as an `EntityObject`, so you can't (purely with typesafe compiled code) make use of the fact that it's, e.g. a `MyEntity` sometimes...unless you also make a `MyEntityUser : User<MyEntity>` class.