# Contravariance/Covariance, why can't cast this?

Tags: c#, casting, covariance, contravariance

Let's face it, I am still having some difficulties to understand the constrains when it's time to use covariance and contravariance in generics.

I wonder, why if I have this:

```
public interface IFasterListCov<out T>
{}

public interface IFasterListCon<in T>
{}

public class FasterList<T> : IList<T>, IFasterListCov<T>, IFasterListCon<T>
```

The third cast fails:

```
public void QueryNodes<T>() where T:INode
{
     //somehow I can convert IFasterListCon<INode> to IFasterListCon<T>
     IFasterListCon<INode> nodes = (IFasterListCon<INode>)_nodesDB[type];
     //I guess this works because _nodesDB[type] is indeed a FasterList<T> object
     //note: I am wrong, I can cast whatever INode implementation, not just T, which made me very confused :P
     IFasterListCon<T> nodesT = (IFasterListCon<T>)nodes; 
     //I can't cast IFasterListCon<T> back to FasterList<T>
     FasterList<T> nodeI = nodesT as FasterList<T>; //null
}

Dictionary<Type, IFasterListCov<INode>>  _nodesDB;

to be clear _nodesDB[type] is a FasterList<T> declared through IFasterListCov<INode>
```

Comment: What is the _actual_ type of `nodesT`? You're doing a _downcast_ which only works if the underlying type is compatible.

Comment: you mean what is T? T must implement INode (the constrain is in the where clause)...ah ok _nodesDB contains all FasterList<INode>

Comment: A `FasterList<INode>` is not a `FasterList<T>` unless `T` is `INode`.

Comment: so the fact T implements INode is not enough? I mean in memory is still a reference in both cases right? The datastructure should be compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyType : IMyType` does not make `Generic<IMyType>` and `Generic<MyType>` related in any way.

In your particular case it is likely that `nodesT` is `FasterList<Node>` which is *not* `FasterList<INode>`.

Note that this conversion work for interface which support variance (co/contra) when you can specify `in`/`out` as you see in successful conversion to interface. See one of many questions for details - i.e. [Generic Class Covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077122/generic-class-covariance).

There is also excellent answer about `List` co-variance - [C# variance problem: Assigning List<Derived> as List<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase) which shows that `List<Derived>` and `List<Base>` can't be cast between each other:

```
List<Giraffes> giraffes = new List<Giraffes>();
List<Animals> animals = new List<Animals>() {new Lion()};

(giraffes as List<Animals>).Add(new Lion()); // What? Lion added to Girafes
Giraffe g = (animals as List<Giraffes>)[0] ; // What? Lion here?
```

Comment: FasterList<Node> is not FasterList<INode> even if Node implements INode?

Comment: Yes - see awesome explanation with Giraffes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033912/c-sharp-variance-problem-assigning-listderived-as-listbase (talks about concrete classes, but it applies the same to interface/class pair)

Comment: ok I understand that the language wants to protect a FasterList<T> to be casted to IFasterListCon<INode>...but in this case it's the other way around. I am casting to the specialization, not the generalization.

Comment: @sebas I've updated my answer with sample based on Jon's answer that possibly makes it clear.

Comment: the example is clear, it's just that in that context there is an upcasting (giraffe->animals), while I am downcasting (INode->T) however I am noticing that I can assign to IFasterListCon<T> whatever class implements INode, which made me even more confused, so I think there is something I am still missing. Probably my confusion comes to the fact that I believe that T and INode are related, while the language doesn't assume that. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Ok I think I understood, IFasterListCov<INode> could potentially hold different type of INode...my confusion is due to the fact that I was looking at it from the wrong angle. I was seeing IFasterListCov<INode> as a generalization of FasterList<T> not INode as a generalization of T. BTW this is a good answer too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719954/understanding-covariant-and-contravariant-interfaces-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario where you're calling `QueryNodes<MyNode>`, in order for your last cast to get a non-null value, the actual instance that you get with `_nodesDB[type]` must be a `FasterList<MyNode>`. It's not good enough for it to be `FasterList<SomeOtherMostlyCompatibleNode>`.

The runtime is very strict about types, it keeps track of the actual runtime types of everything involved, it's not good enough for the data types to be similar, or for you to only have `MyNode` objects populating your `FasterList<SomeOtherMostlyCompatibleNode>`, or anything else. If the types are not *exactly* what they should be, you need to do some sort of programmatic conversion, not just cast.

Comment: wait sorry, I was not clear...the FasterList node contains MyNode elements, it's just that I declare it through INode. So FasterList<INode>.Add(MyNode)...pseudo code if makes sense.