# How to cast A<T> to A<object>?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm trying to create a simulator using characters, and I use many generics to work with their properties regardless of their exact type (weight, length, time, etc). This way, I can still compare them or generate them randomly.

In a certain class, I want to link each character property with a distribution method (for example, link the age with a normal distribution), regardless of the type.
Both the character properties and the distribution method use generics, so I used  as a type. In the dictionnary below, I just want the property and the distribution method to have the same type.

```
public Dictionary<CharacterProperty<object>, PropertyDistributor<object>> properties = new Dictionary<CharacterProperty<object>, PropertyDistributor<object>>();

//example
properties.Add(new CharacterProperty<Time>(
        c => c.age,
        (c, v) => c.age = v
    ), new NormalDistribution<Time>(20 * Time.Y, 35 * Time.Y)
);
```

Here is an example of a method using this dictionnary to generate a character. I create a empty character then generate each of the properties using a distribution method. I don't use types in this method because the distribution method returns an object of the type of the property.

```
Character c = new Character();
foreach(KeyValuePair<CharacterProperty<object>, PropertyDistributor<object>> v in repartitor.properties)
    v.Key.set(c, v.Value.generate());
return c;
```

Though I don't get any error in the function above, I get one when I try to add an element to my dictionnary.

```
Impossible cast from CharacterProperty<Time> to CharacterProperty<object>
```

Why is this cast impossible ?
How should I do to avoid this error ?

Comment: You can't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077122/generic-class-covariance *C# 4 and above support covariance and contravariance of generic interfaces and generic delegates when they are constructed with reference types*. So no covariance/contravariance for `class`es.

Comment: Just because `Time` is an `object` it doesn't mean that `CharacterProperty<Time>` is a `CharacterProperty<object>`. It's not. Otherwise you could cast a `List<Dog>` to `List<Animal>` and then add a `Cat` to the list. That wouldn't work.

Comment: What should I do then ?
I don't want to create a list for each of my types.

Comment: @F.Morival - Internally use a `Dictionary<object, object>` and externally use generic methods and reflection to access the elements of the dictionary. Or perhaps `Dictionary<CharacterPropertyBase, PropertyDistributorBase>` and use generic methods...