# What makes ValueTuple covariant?

Tags: c#, covariance, valuetuple

This compiles correctly in C# 7.3 (Framework 4.8):

```
(string, string) s = ("a", "b");
(object, string) o = s;
```

I know that this is syntactic sugar for the following, which also compiles correctly:

```
ValueTuple<string, string> s = new ValueTuple<string, string>("a", "b");
ValueTuple<object, string> o = s;
```

So, it appears that ValueTuples can be assigned [covariantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), *which is awesome*!

Unfortunately, I don't understand *why*: I was under the impression that C# [only supported covariance on interfaces and delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19094386/87698). `ValueType` is neither.

In fact, when I try to duplicate this feature with my own code, I fail:

```
struct MyValueTuple<A, B>
{
    public A Item1;
    public B Item2;

    public MyValueTuple(A item1, B item2)
    {
        Item1 = item1;
        Item2 = item2;
    }
}

...

MyValueTuple<string, string> s = new MyValueTuple<string, string>("a", "b");
MyValueTuple<object, string> o = s;
// ^ Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyValueTuple<string, string>' to 'MyValueTuple<object, string>'
```

So, why can `ValueTuple`s be assigned covariantly, but `MyValueTuple`s can't?

Comment: This is likely special treatment by the compiler, just like how you can assign `null` to a `Nullable<T>` even though it's a struct.

Comment: Actually, the decompiled code looks like this for the second assignment: `ValueTuple<object, string> o = new ValueTuple<object, string>(s.Item1, s.Item2);`

Comment: Tuples are weird and are implemented entirely in the c# compiler front end, instead of relying on an underlying CLR representation. That assignment operator isn't doing what you think.

Comment: Add an implicit operator `public static implicit operator MyValueTuple<A, B>(MyValueTuple<string, string> v)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }` its deconstructing the assignment. Also, great question by the way!

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ bulls eye! that makes it compileable, and the exception is thrown as expected

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I believe what is actually happening here is a destructuring assignment. Tuple assignment will try to implicitly convert its components, and as it is possible to assign `string` to `object`, that is what happens here.

> The language supports assignment between tuple types that have the same number of elements, where each right-hand side element can be implicitly converted to its corresponding left-hand side element. Other conversions aren't considered for assignments.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#assignment-and-tuples)

[See it on sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjaSBAAwA0yjlAzogLyKkBEAQz4s+AIz7kA3NRo5SAe1EArAKYBjAC4t6DSvO6J20mLNz0AnAqkzEAX1i2gA)

Comment: I just tried it on SharpLab and sure enough [it does exactly that](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjaSBAAwA0yjlAzogLyKkBEAQz4s+AIz7kA3NRo5SAe1EArAKYBjAC4t6DSvO6J20mLNz0AnAqkzEAX1i2gA).

Comment: Just to reinforce that, in OP's original example, if you change `s` to type `(string, object)` it results in a conversion error, indicating that implicit conversion is taking place between the items, and string can be implicitly converted to string, but not vice versa.