# How to convert derived class inside a wrapper class generic in c#

Tags: c#, generics, derived-class

```cs
using System;

class X {}
class Y: X {}

class Wrapper<T> where T : X {}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapper<Y> y = new();
        
        Wrapper<X> x = y; // Error here
    }
}
```

The error is `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Wrapper<Y>' to 'Wrapper<X>'`

Here I want to convert `Wrapper<Y>` into `Wrapper<X>`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should look at the doc pages [Covariance and contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) and [Creating Variant Generic Interfaces (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces)

Comment: And also the questions [Generic Class Covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19077122), [Difference between Covariance & Contra-variance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2184551) and [Cast Generic<Derived> to Generic<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41179199).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by having a covariant interface. And you won't need the where clause either.

```
class X { }
class Y : X { }

interface IWrapper<out T> {
    
}

class Wrapper<T> : IWrapper<T> 
{
    
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWrapper<Y> y = new Wrapper<Y>();

        IWrapper<X> x = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though i just need the interface for Wrapper class, it still needs interface for covariant?

Comment: @kennarddh read this please. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces

Comment: Then i make a function that return `IWrapper<Y>`, and i also have `IWrapper<X>[]`, but i cant put the y into x array.. like IWrapper<X>[0] = y. how can i do this? or its just not possible? i got ArrayTypeMismatchException..

Comment: @kennarddh That doesn't work with arrays. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619139/covariance-and-contravariance-with-c-sharp-arrays

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, in the general case. Consider the following example: `y` is a `List<Y>`, `x` is a `List<X>`. This means it should be legal to do `x.Add(new X())` (because you can do it with a `List<X>`), but if it is actually a `List<Y>`, this would be an illegal operation, since `new X()` is not of type `Y`. It doesn't work the other way around either, because that would break reading operations like `y[0]`. This is called template covariance and contravariance, and you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

Comment: What if i want to create a list of anything that derived from X? so List<?> will accept add(y) and add(x)?

Comment: @kennarddh In that case you just use a `List<X>`. It will then be able to store any objects of type `X` and ones derived from it, including `Y`