# Nested Generics and Dependency Injection C#

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm relatively new to dependency injection. I think I get the idea, but I'm now presented with this problem. Assume that I have some interfaces and some classes:

```
interface IA<T>
interface IB<IA<T>>
class A<T> : IA<T>
class B<IA<T>> : IB<IA<T>>
```

I want to register the following in my dependency injection container:

```
container.Register<IB<IA<T>>, B<A<T>>(...);
```

When I try to resolve `IB<IA<T>>`, it fails with an exception explaining that `IB<IA<T>>` cannot be converted to `B<A<T>>`.

Why did it fail, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997923/non-generic-implementations-of-generic-interfaces#comment42526942_26997923 question have explanation of why part (there are plenty of the explanations of covariance in C#... feel free to search for one you like). How to fix would depend on what you actually trying to achieve/what restrictions you are ok to put on your interfaces - consider to read on covariance and clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Alexei posted already you wouldn't use generics that way. You would probably want something like this instead:

```
public interface IA<T>
{
    T Item { get; }
}

public interface IB<T>
{
    IA<T> IA { get; }
}
```

Sample implementations:

```
public class A<T> : IA<T> 
{
    public T Item
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class B<T> : IB<T>
{
    public B(IA<T> ia)
    {
        this.IA = ia;
    }

    public IA<T> IA
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Since the subject is dependency injection notice the B implementation does not have parameterless constructor. Instead it notifies its dependency in the constructor.

Setting up the container, first register IA implementation:

```
        container.Register<IA<int>, A<int>>(); // specific implementation or
        container.Register(typeof(IA<>), typeof(A<>)); // generic registration
```

Registering IB would be the same and the container should take care of injecting the dependency to class B's constructor:

```
        container.Register<IB<int>, B<int>>();
        container.Register(typeof(IB<>), typeof(B<>));
```

Resolving at runtime you would need to specify the type:

```
        var intIB = container.Resolve<IB<int>>();
        var stringIB = container.Resolve<IB<string>>();
```