# .Net 6.0 Unable to resolve service for type 'EFCoreRepository' while attempting to activate 'EFCoreService'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm totally new to .Net and I'm trying to build a skeleton project from scratch.

Firstly, I write the IEntity class, which represents the basic entity, simple and easy as the following:

```
    public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I make a repository interface, which looks like this:

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEntity
    {
       //...... some methods 
    }
```

And a basic implementation of this interface, which looks like this:

```
    public class EFCoreRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
        where TContext : DBContext
    {
        protected readonly TContext _context;

        public EFCoreRepository(TContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }
        // ...... some methods
    }
```

A service interface, which looks like this

```
    public interface IService<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity 
    {
       // ...... some methods
    }
```

And a basic implementation of this service interface, which looks like this:

```
     public class EFCoreService<TEntity, TRepo> : IService<TEntity> 
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
        where TRepo : EFCoreRepository<TEntity, DBContext>
    {
        protected readonly TRepo _repository;

        public EFCoreService(TRepo repository) { 
            _repository = repository;
        }
        // ...... some methods
    }
```

And I registered them in program.cs like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<IEntity>, EFCoreRepository<IEntity, DBContext>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IService<IEntity>, EFCoreService<IEntity, EFCoreRepository<IEntity, DBContext>>>();
```

You may notice that it is `DBContext` rather than `DbContext`. It is not a typo, `DBContext` is my customized class that extends `DbContext`.

When I tried to build the project, I got this run time error：

```
Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 
ServiceType: IService<IEntity> 
Lifetime: Scoped 
ImplementationType: EFCoreService<IEntity,EFCoreRepository<IEntity,DBContext>> 

Unable to resolve service for type EFCoreRepository<IEntity,DBContext> while attempting to activate EFCoreService<IEntity,EFCoreRepository<IEntity,DBContext>>
```

Can anyone find the cause of this error? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

-------------------------------------- An additional question -----------------------------------

What I'm trying to do above is to register a common service, so any service that implements the base service can have the corresponding implemented methods. For example, if there is an entity called `Item` and its service interface and implementation are extended from the base service, they should be automatically registered (ready to be injected as a dependency) and have the base-class-implemented methods, like this:

```
    public interface IItemService : IService<Item>
    {

    }

    public class ItemService : EFCoreService<Item, ItemRepository>
    {
        public ItemService(ItemRepository repository) : base(repository)
        {
        }
    }
```

Is this possible to achieve by the above code?

Comment: You're registering the `EFCoreRepository<IEntity, DBContext>` as `IRepository<IEntity>` in DI, however, the `EFCoreService` class expects `EFCoreRepository<IEntity, DBContext>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code.
Create a `DBContext` act like table for test.

```
    public class DBContext 
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product(){ Id=1 ,Name="Coke"},
            new Product(){ Id=2,Name="Pepsi"}

        };
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }
```

Add `TContext` to `IRepository` and create a `get()` method for test. (should get first product name which is "coke")

```
    public class EFCoreRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity, TContext> where TEntity : class, IEntity
        where TContext : DBContext
    {
        protected readonly TContext _context;

        public EFCoreRepository(TContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
        }
        // ...... some methods
        public string get()
        {
            return _context.products.FirstOrDefault().Name;
        }
    }
```

So the `IRepository.cs` changed

```
    public interface IRepository<TEntity, TContext> where TEntity : class, IEntity where TContext : class
    {
        string get();
    }
```

In `EFCoreService`,Inject `EFCoreRepository` instead of add generic type `TRepo`

```
    public class EFCoreService<TEntity> : IService<TEntity>
            where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        private readonly EFCoreRepository<TEntity, DBContext> _repository;

        public EFCoreService(EFCoreRepository<TEntity,DBContext> repository)
        {
            this._repository = repository;
        }
        // ...... some methods
        public string get()
        {
            
            return _repository.get();
        }
    }
```

So the `IService` also changed

```
    public interface IService<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        // ...... some methods
        string get();
    }
```

Register Services in `program.cs`.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<DBContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(EFCoreRepository<,>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<,>), typeof(EFCoreRepository<,>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<>), typeof(EFCoreService<>));
```

Controller for test

```
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IService<Item> _service;

        public ValuesController(IService<Item> service)
        {
            this._service = service;
        }
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public string test()
        {
            return _service.get();
        }
    }
```

Output
[image]

Reference this answer:[Nested Generics and Dependency Injection C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006380/nested-generics-and-dependency-injection-c-sharp)